# Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must have required property 'outputPath'

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend

I get this error while trying a simple poc for microfrontend with angular.
Here is the [link](https://github.com/ishedu/module-federation-angular/tree/main) to code sample.

I get the error with this command:

```
npm run start:app1
```

---

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must have required property 'outputPath'.
```

Comment: Can you share your `angular.json` config ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was because of the name of builder in angular.json.

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
...
}
```

should be:

```
"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
```